# Trying to send array over socket

Tags: python, arrays, sockets, pygame, pickle

Ok so I am trying to send an array over a sockets. The array is the axis of a joy stick so x,y,z,slider.

So then i send it over a socket once and I receive it at the other end and then unpickle it where I get the error

It gives me the error `_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow` im not really sure what it means but I have read it is because the array is getting cut off.
Client(Uses Pygame to get joystick axis)

```
    x = j.get_axis(0)
    y = j.get_axis(1)
    slide = j.get_axis(2)
    z = j.get_axis(3)
    array = (x, y, slide, z)
    send_array = pickle.dumps(array)
```

and just send the array with `socket.send(send_array)`
and then I receive and just try to print it for testing purposes.

```
        raw_message = sc.recv(1024)
        (data1, data2, data3, data4) = pickle.loads(raw_message)
        print (data1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Client:

```
import socket, pickle

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
arr = (YOUR ARRAY)
data_string = pickle.dumps(arr)
s.send(data_string)

data = s.recv(4096)
data_arr = pickle.loads(data)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data_arr)
```

Server:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(4096)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: I am using `variable = pickle.loads(retrieved message)` but it is still giving me the error

Comment: Ok data is getting lost somewhere in the sending through the socket

Comment: probably in that while 1 ... instead he should send a terminal sentinal of some sort ... (that cannot be in a pickle ideally `\x00\x01` or something) and then wait for that instead of just bailing once you dont recieve anything ... just a guess ... that seems like the likely point of failure ... also use checksums or something or use a handshaking protocol like TCP  (lathoughh if its just local it really shouldnt be losing packets...)

Comment: [Solved] Found a small piece in my code where I actually sent something that was not an array.